# WPF C# - How do I avoid grouping taskbar icons?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, taskbar

When I create a new window using `.Show()`, it shows the new window, however my icons are grouped like below:

[image]

I don't want that. I want the icons to be separate because I want my users to easily open the window that they want instead of having to click it, view the list of open windows, then choosing which one they want every time. I **don't** want to use `.ShowDialog()` because I need the users to be able to focus on either window no matter the state of the other. Meaning, both windows will need to be open and the user will need to be able to interact with each of those windows regardless of if the other window is open or minimized.

I've tried setting the parent, but I don't think I'm taking the right approach. I've never worked with icons before, so excuse my lack of knowledge.

```
var w = new Window();
w.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
w.Show();
```

I will be changing the icon of the second window that gets opened so that the user knows which one to click on based on what they want. I'm just trying to get around the grouping that seems to be the default.

Comment: But isn't this a user preference in Windows? Why try to control what a user has set on their system?

Comment: @CharlesMay This is where my lack of knowledge hurts. I have no idea if it's a preference in Windows. I was hoping that this is a configurable property in WPF. Since we can change certain properties in the window itself, I was hoping that I could change this.

Answer (score 3):

(If i'm correct) In Windows it's possible to assign a seperate **AppUserModelID** to your shortcut icon to prevent the default grouping of icons, [this is the page explaining how to define and assign a seperate AppUserModelID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459(v=vs.85).aspx). I would suggest reading the provided source thouroughly.

Comment: Relevant extract from the MSDN page: "If different windows owned by one process require different AppUserModelIDs to control taskbar grouping, use SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow) to retrieve the window's property store and set the AppUserModelID as a window property."