# Show Child form separately in task

Tags: c#, winforms

I have main form and child form. when my child form opens from button in main form, it shows behind the main form icon in taskbar.
How can i show the child form as separate icon in taskbar

here is the code i am using

```
    child childform = new child();
               
    childform.Show();
```

[image]

as shown in above image now the child form shows behind the main form in taskbar.
What i need is child form to show separate icon in taskbar

Comment: I don't know whether or not that's possible (using a hacky way perhaps) but please don't do this unless you have a very good reason. This is something that is handled by Windows settings. Users will probably hate you for overriding their preferences.

Comment: It would probably have to be in its own process.

Comment: Can you add the image what you are looking for?

Comment: @LarsTech Not necessarily. [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://github.com/m417z/7-Taskbar-Tweaker) does it (even to 3rd-party processes) by injecting into Explorer, but yeah, running a new process is probably easier, of course. I still don't recommend this without a good reason though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847905/wpf-c-sharp-how-do-i-avoid-grouping-taskbar-icons